# jquery animate not working with easing other than linear

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

i have written jquery to animate one div and it works fine if i don't mention any easing effect, or if i mention 'linear' but i want 'easeInOutBack' easing effect here and can't understand what is going wrong.

Hope someone tells me where i am missing out something.

Please give solutions in a simple language if possible because i am new to jQuery. :) :|

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('div.button').on('click', function () {
        $('div.box').animate({
            marginLeft: 200
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'easeOutBack'
        });
    });
});
```

Is not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include jquery UI for that

From docs:

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins,
>   most notably the jQuery UI suite.

- http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Comment: its my first post and wow.. thanks for such a quick response... can u please tell me where can i get the UI?

Comment: @india_developer _its my first post_ - Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Comment: sorry for my question again - there are number of files in that archive.. which one is to included for the effect that i want?

and is the method of including it similar to including jquery library (jquery1.9.1.min.js) ?

Comment: include this file `-->` http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js    same as you include jquery...and make sure you include after jquery

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) included.

Check out this fiddle, it works fine with `easeInOutBack` when jQueryUI is included.

http://jsfiddle.net/AHnDb/